# In Angular Edit Mode, I need to get the selected value from the dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript

**On Edit Mode, I need to get the value from the dropdown**(disabled as its in edit mode)
that will be used for getting another control's(`ExistingBalanace`) value which will be shown on the page along with all other control's data that'd be populated from DB. Screenshot shown below.

Here are the tasks done for this

1. From Index page `Edit` button is clicked
2. It takes to the page on `Edit Mode`
3. The code to fetch data on `Edit mode` is given below
4. The statement `...subscribe(x => this.creditTransactionForm.patchValue(x)`sets all controls but one (`ExistingBalance`) as this is calculated as another service call using the selected value at the dropdown(account list)
5. `this.getAndSetOpenCreditTrans();` is the method that uses the selected AccountId (drpodown's value) to calculate the value for the control `Existing Balance`
   --> I'm trying to assign value to selectedAccountId but do not know how to (*In AddMode onChange event of dropdown the selecteAccountId is populated*)

**My Query**

1. I need help on how I should get the value of selectedAccountId before calling the method `this.getAndSetOpenCreditTrans();`
2. a. Where should I assign the value for SelectedAccountId?

   b. Where can I get the value from the control dropdown for AccountId
   to assign it to selectedAccountId?

Any solution to address this will be a great help for me.

```
**Code to fetch data on Edit mode**
```

> ```
>   ngOnInit(): void {
>   this.id = this.route.snapshot.params["creditTransactionId"];
>   this.isAddMode = !this.id;
>   this.getAccounts();
>   this.getProducts();
>   console.log("ngOnInit");  
>
>   this.creditTransactionForm = this.formBuilder.group({ 
>     creditTransactionId: new FormControl(0),
>     
>     accountId:new FormControl(''),
>     
>     creditTransactionDate: new FormControl(new Date(Date.now()), [Validators.required]),
>     creditAmount: new FormControl(0, [Validators.required]),
>     receiptAmount:new FormControl(0, [Validators.required]),
>     ...
>     ...
>     productId:new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
>   }); 
>   
>   this.onChanges();
>
>   if (!this.isAddMode) {
>     this.creditTransService.getById(this.id)
>       .pipe(first())
>       .subscribe(x => this.creditTransactionForm.patchValue(x)
>       );
>        // below 2 lines are fetching ''  for accountId     
>       //this.selectedAccountId = this.creditTransactionForm.get("accountId").value;
>       //this.selectedAccountId=this.creditTransactionForm.value.accountId;
>       this.getAndSetOpenCreditTrans();
>     console.log(this.creditTransactionForm.controls);
>   }
> }
> ```

**The code that calculates the Existing Balance using Dropdown's value i.e. `selectAccountId`**

> ```
>     getAndSetOpenCreditTrans() { 
>       this.creditTransService.getOpenCreditTrans(this.selectedAccountId).subscribe((data:CreditTransaction)=>{
>     this.openCreditTransaction = data;console.log(this.openCreditTransaction);
>     this.existingBal=this.openCreditTransaction.balanceAmount;
>
>     
>     let bal= parseFloat(this.existingBal)+ parseFloat(this.creditTransactionForm.value.creditAmount)-parseFloat(this.creditTransactionForm.value.receiptAmount);
>    
>    this.newNowBalance = bal.toString();
>    
> });     
> }
> ```

Below screenshot shows the page where the Existing Balance does not have a value
[image]

Comment: Hello! Could you look at my example? Does this cover your needs? 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmfmw8?file=src/main.ts

If yes, I will add the answer

Comment: I'm not sure as I am not able to select and populate accordingly in this sample code.
My problem now is --> on `EditMode` (am using `PatchValue` to populate all the control values from DB except ExistngBalance which uses another method to get its value w.r.t the selected `AccountId`)

I do not know how to get the `AccountId` from the statement `this.creditTransService.getById(this.id)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(x => this.creditTransactionForm.patchValue(x)` to a variable (selectedAccountId)
If this is done then issue will get resolved.

Comment: Note : Its working fine in `AddMode`  - as on Onchange of Account dropdown , `selectedAccountId` gets assigned

The issue is only in the `EditMode` - as `SelectedAccountId` has no value and gets value on `OnChange` dropdown event

Comment: Ok, look at this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bydbiy?file=src/main.ts,
line 106, i added a spread operator and add additional properties.

Comment: Thanks Nikita for a quick reply.
The problem I encountered was when it was populated on Edit Mode
Please  excuse me am not able to figure that out here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue.
I moved the call of the `getAndSetOpenCreditTrans` method inside Subscribe and it started working fine.
The change I've made to the above code is as shown below.

> 

```
    if (!this.isAddMode) {          
      this.creditTransService.getById(this.id)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe((x) => {
        this.creditTransactionForm.patchValue(x);
        console.log(x.AccountId);
        this.getAndSetOpenCreditTrans(); 
      }
    );
  }
```